# Collect custom commands from various files into a separate page

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have some C++ classes in my application, which have some "config" members that the end user can modify at runtime to choose various configurations. (How this is implemented under the covers is not relevant and skipped.) I want to collect custom documentation of all such config members into a separate doxygen page which the user can refer to, to know all the config members that exist.

Consider this simple example. (The relevant code need not be at the top of the class declaration, as it is shown here.)

```
class Foo {
public:
  /**
    * @config Foo12
    * @default true
    * @range true, false
    * @purpose set this false if you don't want Foo12
    */
  bool foo12;

  /**
    * @config Foo34
    * @default false
    * @range true, false
    * @purpose set this true if you want Foo34
    */
  bool foo34;
};

class Bar {
public:
  /**
    * @config Bar12
    * @default true
    * @range true, false
    * @purpose set this false if you don't want Bar12
    */
  bool bar12;    
};
```

This should produce an output something like the following:

> **Config: Foo12**
>   **Default** true
>   **Range** true, false
>   **Purpose** set this false if you don't want Foo12
>   
>   **Config: Foo34**
>   **Default** false
>   **Range** true, false
>   **Purpose** set this false if you want Foo34
>   
>   **Config: Bar12**
>   **Default** true
>   **Range** true, false
>   **Purpose** set this false if you don't want Bar12

I am moderately familiar with [Grouping](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html), [`\xrefitem`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdxrefitem), [ALIASES](http://www.doxygen.nl/config.html#cfg_aliases), [Custom Commands](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/custcmd.html), but I am unable to figure out how to use them together to achieve the above.

`\xrefitem` creates a separate page per custom command. Grouping places the documentation wherever it appears in the source. These are not very helpful to show the user all the available config settings in one go.

What approaches could I try to get this working? The solution need not be clean or elegant, use of workarounds is okay.

Answer (score 1):

This any good?

Set up an alias in the doxyfile

```
ALIASES  =  "wibble=@xrefitem wibble \"Wibbles!\" \"Wibble List\""
```

and use

```
@wibble
- \b Config fobbling 
- \b Default 4245345346
- \b Range 500 yards
```

in the code.

Output is not perfect but looks workable to me (I've just tried it).

Comment: Yeah, this is certainly useful, though it creates the document "inline". Let me figure out how I can move (or at least copy) that into a separate page.

Comment: When I did this, it put the entries both in-line _and_ on a separate "Wibbles!" page in the document.  Do you mean separate page or separate file?